# Light weight text/code editor that can open .SLN, and .CSProj Files

Tags: visual-studio, ide, editor, performance, desktop-application

I'm using a weak computer that's chokes when I open too many programs (Out of my control).

So I want to have a lighter way to open Visual Studio solution files and csproj files.

I sometimes like to keep projects open for

- code reference
- easy access to files I care about.
- edit my custom msbuild tasks (don't compile thru the IDE)

Just want to eliminate the bloat of running a full blown IDE unnecessarily.

Know any apps or plugins for editors I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 4):

Have you thought about [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)?

It's just like Visual Studio except it's open source and written in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs, VIM, VS Express?

Or [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) ?.

Comment: Hang on. Mono isn't just and IDE. It's a whole different .NET compiler.

Comment: Mono develop on windows requires .NET FX 3.5 and doesn't depend on Mono.